# Should I make my MutexLock volatile?

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, mutex

I have some code in a function that goes something like this:

```
void foo() {
    { // scope the locker
      MutexLocker locker(&mutex);
      // do some stuff..
    }
    bar();
}
```

The function call `bar()` also locks the mutex.

I am having an issue whereby the program crashes (for someone else, who has not as yet provided a stack trace or more details) unless the mutex lock inside `bar` is disabled.

Is it possible that some optimization is messing around with the way I have scoped the `locker` instance, and if so, would making the mutex `volatile` fix it? Is that a bad idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Do bar and foo use the same mutex? if so, does your mutex support re-lock?

Comment: @Change - Why and why? I mean, if they were different mutexes, what would be the point of the question? And re-locking is just asking for trouble.

Comment: I mean trying to acquire the lock that you already acquire in the same thread. Not all mutex implementation supports such operation. volatile just disable compiler optimization of accessing variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think someone can actually answer the question, as we (and so do you) haven't seen the stack back-trace.

> Is it possible that some optimization is messing around

Yes, it is, but it's very, very unlikely. Maybe in more than 99% of the cases, the problem is in the code, not in the optimizations.

**However, it *is possible* that the compiler optimizations "unlock" some other bugs, most likely - *undefined behavior*, that works fine without optimizations and with them - the *UB* becomes a crash** *

> making it volatile fix it? Is that a bad idea

I don't think it will fix anything and I don't think you need `volatile` for this.
I use wrapper around POSIX threads with `class Mutex` and `class MutexLock`, the logic is the same as in your case, and there's no `volatile` in these classes (except some `bool` flags and the thread id, but this seems to be irrelevant to the case)

---

"*" I recently had such case - when we compiled an application with `-O2`, strange crashes appeared. We investigated this for months, we couldn't find anything suspicious. Then removed the optimizations and everything started working fine again.
Several months later, I found the issue and it appeared to be multithreading one - returning const ref on a place, that we shouldn't have done this.

Comment: Thanks @Kiril. Some food for thought there.

Comment: @sje397 - you're welcome :) I know this doesn't help much and does not answer the question, but it may give you some ideas. You may post the stack trace, once it's available, it may give us some more info. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, locking operations on mutexes introduce implicit memory fences and thus declaring it volatile is not necessary. The problem is likely somewhere else.